# Possible to Simplify These Python Regular Expressions?

Tags: python, regex

```
    patterns = {}
    patterns[1] = re.compile("[A-Z]\d-[A-Z]\d")
    patterns[2] = re.compile("[A-Z]\d-[A-Z]\d\d")
    patterns[3] = re.compile("[A-Z]\d\d-[A-Z]\d\d")
    patterns[4] = re.compile("[A-Z]\d\d-[A-Z]\d\d\d")
    patterns[5] = re.compile("[A-Z]\d\d\d-[A-Z]\d\d\d")
    patterns[6] = re.compile("[A-Z][A-Z]\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d")
    patterns[7] = re.compile("[A-Z][A-Z]\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d")
    patterns[8] = re.compile("[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d")
    patterns[9] = re.compile("[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d")
    patterns[10] = re.compile("[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d")

    def matchFound(toSearch):
        for items in sorted(patterns.keys(), reverse=True):
            matchObject = patterns[items].search(toSearch)
            if matchObject:
                return items
        return 0
```

then I use the following code to look for matches:

```
        while matchFound(toSearch) > 0:
```

I have 10 different regular expressions but I feel like they could be replaced by one, well written, more elegant regular expression. Do you guys think it's possible?

EDIT: FORGOT TWO MORE EXPRESSIONS:

```
  patterns[11] = re.compile("[A-Z]\d-[A-Z]\d\d\d")
  patterns[12] = re.compile("[A-Z][A-Z]\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d")
```

EDIT2: I ended up with the following. I realize I COULD get extra results but I don't think they're possible in the data I'm parsing.

```
    patterns = {}
    patterns[1] = re.compile("[A-Z]{1,2}\d-[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,3}")
    patterns[2] = re.compile("[A-Z]{1,2}\d\d-[A-Z]{1,2}\d{2,3}")
    patterns[3] = re.compile("[A-Z]{1,2}\d\d\d-[A-Z]{1,2}\d\d\d")
```

Comment: Aside from patterns.join('|') I presume :P

Comment: Multiple regular expressions can *always* be replaced by a single regular expression if you want to say "find something that matches any of these".  Your intuition is serving you well here.  Proof: Join the strings defining the regular expressions with a '|' character and you've constructed it.  That being said, in this case Sean has produced one for you that further simplifies what I just explained.

Comment: Not actually answering your question (I believe Sean already did) I'd like to recommend the cheat-sheet I use. I personally use regexp pretty rare, that's why I always consult with this chetsheet - http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/ - I find it very useful. Just print it out and out somewhere around your desk :)

Comment: No, my answer was wrong which is why I deleted it.  I'm fairly certain that you can't simplify this much more because the number of repeating elements in the second piece rely on the number of repeated elements in the first.  You might be able to eliminate a few of these with quantifiers, but not all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Josh Caswell noted that Sean Bright's answer will match more inputs than your original group.  Sorry I didn't figure this out.  (In the future it might be good to spell out your problem a little bit more.)

So your basic problem is that regular expressions can't count.  But we can still solve this in Python in a very slick way.  First we make a pattern that matches any of your legal inputs, but would also match some you want to reject.

Next, we define a function that uses the pattern and then examines the match object, and counts to make sure that the matched string meets the length requirements.

```
import re
_s_pat = r'([A-Z]{1,2})(\d{1,3})-([A-Z]{1,2})(\d{1,3})'
_pat = re.compile(_s_pat)

_valid_n_len = set([(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)])
def check_match(s):
    m = _pat.search(s)
    try:
        a0, n0, a1, n1 = m.groups()
        if len(a0) != len(a1):
            return False
        if not (len(n0), len(n1)) in _valid_n_len:
            return False
        return True
    except (AttributeError, TypeError, ValueError):
        return False
```

Here is some explanation of the above code.

First we use a raw string to define the pattern, and then we pre-compile the pattern.  We could just stuff the literal string into the call to `re.compile()` but I like to have a separate string.  Our pattern has four distinct sections enclosed in parentheses; these will become "match groups".  There are two match groups to match the alphabet characters, and two match groups to match numbers.  This one pattern will match everything you want, but won't exclude some stuff you don't want.

Next we declare a `set` that has all the valid lengths for numbers.  For example, the first group of numbers can be 1 digit long and the second group can be 2 digits; this is `(1,2)` (a `tuple` value).  A set is a nice way to specify all the possible combinations that we want to be legal, while still being able to check quickly whether a given pair of lengths is legal.

The function `check_match()` first uses the pattern to match against the string, returning a "match object" which is bound to the name `m`.  If the search fails, `m` might be set to `None`.  Instead of explicitly testing for `None`, I used a `try`/`except` block; in retrospect it might have been better to just test for `None`.  Sorry, I didn't mean to be confusing.  But the `try`/`except` block is a pretty simple way to wrap something and make it very reliable, so I often use it for things like this.

Finally, `check_match()` unpacks the match groups into four variables.  The two alpha groups are a0 and a1, and the two number groups are n0 and n1.  Then it checks that the lengths are legal.  As far as I can tell, the rule is that alpha groups need to be the same length; and then we build a `tuple` of number group lengths and check to see if the `tuple` is in our `set` of valid `tuple`s.

Here's a slightly different version of the above.  Maybe you will like it better.

```
import re
# match alpha: 1 or 2 capital letters
_s_pat_a = r'[A-Z]{1,2}'
# match number: 1-3 digits
_s_pat_n = r'\d{1,3}'

# pattern: four match groups: alpha, number, alpha, number
_s_pat = '(%s)(%s)-(%s)(%s)' % (_s_pat_a, _s_pat_n, _s_pat_a, _s_pat_n)
_pat = re.compile(_s_pat)

# set of valid lengths of number groups
_valid_n_len = set([(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)])

def check_match(s):
    m = _pat.search(s)
    if not m:
        return False
    a0, n0, a1, n1 = m.groups()
    if len(a0) != len(a1):
        return False
    tup = (len(n0), len(n1)) # make tuple of actual lengths
    if not tup in _valid_n_len:
        return False
    return True
```

Note: It looks like the rule for valid lengths is actually simple:

```
    if len(n0) > len(n1):
        return False
```

If that rule works for you, you could get rid of the set and the tuple stuff.  Hmm, and I'll make the variable names a bit shorter.

```
import re
# match alpha: 1 or 2 capital letters
pa = r'[A-Z]{1,2}'
# match number: 1-3 digits
pn = r'\d{1,3}'

# pattern: four match groups: alpha, number, alpha, number
p = '(%s)(%s)-(%s)(%s)' % (pa, pn, pa, pn)
_pat = re.compile(p)

def check_match(s):
    m = _pat.search(s)
    if not m:
        return False
    a0, n0, a1, n1 = m.groups()
    if len(a0) != len(a1):
        return False
    if len(n0) > len(n1):
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: oh, you were slightly faster than me :-) That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: This looks good but I have to admit I have no idea what this code does.

Edit: Okay after reading the code a bit I think I get it. I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be obscure.  I'll add some explanation after the code.

Answer (score 4):

Sean Bright gave you the answer you need.  Here's just a general tip:

Python has wonderful documentation.  In this case, you could read it with the "help" command:

```
import re
help(re)
```

And if you read through the help, you would see:

```
{m,n}    Matches from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE.
```

It also helps to use Google.  "Python regular expressions" found these links for me:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

Both are worth reading.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I will add them to my favorites.

Answer (score 3):

Josh is right about at least reducing the number of REs.

But you could also take a RE which is wider than allowed and then additionally check if all conditions are met. Such as

```
pattern = re.compile("([A-Z]{1,2})(\d{1,3})-([A-Z]{1,2})(\d{1,3})")
```

and then

```
matchObject = pattern.search(toSearch)
if matchObject and <do something with the length of the groups, comparing them)>:
    return <stuff>
```

But even if that does not work due to any reason, there are ways to improve that:

```
patterns = tuple(re.compile(r) for r in (
    "[A-Z]\d-[A-Z]\d{1,2}",
    "[A-Z]\d\d-[A-Z]\d{2,3}",
    "[A-Z]\d\d\d-[A-Z]\d\d\d",
    "[A-Z][A-Z]\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d{1,2}",
    "[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d{2,3}",
    "[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d",
)

def matchFound(toSearch):
    for pat in reversed(patterns):
        matchObject = pat.search(toSearch)
        if matchObject:
            return items # maybe more useful?
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Sean's (now apparently deleted) answer, you can reduce the number of patterns. Because of the limitations on the combinations of length of digit matches (i.e., if `m` in the first position, at least `m` and no more than 3 in the second) I'm not sure you can get it down to one:

```
"[A-Z]\d-[A-Z]\d{1,3}"
"[A-Z]\d\d-[A-Z]\d{2,3}"
"[A-Z]\d\d\d-[A-Z]\d\d\d"
"[A-Z][A-Z]\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d{1,3}"
"[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d{2,3}"
"[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d-[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d"
```

This uses the `{m,n}` [repeat qualifier syntax](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#repeating-things), which specifies that the immediately preceding match be repeated at least `m` but no more than `n` times. You can also specify a single number `n`; then the match must succeed exactly `n` times:

```
"[A-Z]{2}\d-[A-Z]{2}\d{2,3}"
```

Comment: This is a lot better than what I have. But it also illuminated a logical error on my code. I will edit the question.